# How can I manipulate image pixels in flutter on a perfomant way?

Tags: flutter, ffi

I'm trying to develop an application that works with pixel transformation in Flutter. In my current approach I'm using Rust through FFI to perform all pixel manipulation algorithms, but I've noticed that it hasn't been very performative. In my example I use a slider to change the RED channel from 0 to 255. I suspect I'm not using the best approach to render the image in flutter. I would like suggestions that could help improve performance. Here is an example:

**My Component**

```
class _RedChannelPageState extends State<RedChannelPage> {
  Uint8List? _imageAsBytes;
  double _sliderValue = 0;
  ui.Image? _img;

  void _pickImage() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      final imageAsbytes = await image.readAsBytes();
      loadImage(imageAsBytes).then((value) => {
            setState(() {
              _img = value;
              _imageAsBytes = imageAsbytes;
            })
          });
    }
  }

  Future<ui.Image> loadImage(Uint8List imageAsBytes) async {
    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(imageAsBytes, (ui.Image img) {
      return completer.complete(img);
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  void _onSlideChange(double value) async {
    setState(() {
      _sliderValue = value;
    });
    final imgResult =
        await compute(spawnThread, [_imageAsBytes!, value.round()]);
    final decodedImage = await loadImage(imgResult);
    setState(() {
      _img = decodedImage;
    });
  }

  static Uint8List spawnThread(List<dynamic> list) {
    final result = FFI(imageAsBytes: list[0]).changeRed(list[1]);
    return result;
  }
```

**My FFI class**

```
final Pointer<Uint8> Function(Pointer<Uint8> data, int len, int red)
    nativeRedChannel = nativeAddLib
        .lookup<
            NativeFunction<
                Pointer<Uint8> Function(
                    Pointer<Uint8>, Int32, Int32)>>("red_channel")
        .asFunction();

class FFI {
  const FFI({
    required this.imageAsBytes,
  });
  final Uint8List imageAsBytes;
// send a pointer of Uint8List to rust function and return a encoded JPEG with alterations
  Uint8List changeRed(int redValue) {
    final Pointer<Uint8> allocation =
        malloc.allocate<Uint8>(imageAsBytes.length * sizeOf<Uint8>());
    allocation.asTypedList(imageAsBytes.length).setAll(0, imageAsBytes);
    final pointerResult =
        nativeRedChannel(allocation, imageAsBytes.length, redValue);
    final result = pointerResult.asTypedList(imageAsBytes.length);
    return result;
  }
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln2pn.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reduce calls to the compute method

Given your method name `_onSlideChange` I assume you call this when the slider updates its value, if this is the case - then it might be reasonable to consider **throttling** the compute method, so you don't spawn isolates that is redundant.

Since you are using a Material `Slider` - instead of using the `onChanged` callback, you could consider the `Slider`'s `onChangeEnd` callback, so you only do the `compute` when you let go of the slider thumb.

#### Change the max image resolution

Note, if you don't need the original resolution on the image - then in the ImagePicker plugin you have the option of setting a `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`, which would reduce the workload.

```dart
ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    maxWidth: 1080,
    maxHeight: 1080,
)
```

#### User experience

If the work is taking some time, then it be a good time to use a loading indicator (f.ex. the `CircularProgressIndicator`) in order to show that the app is working. Sometimes, it might be cool to animate in the changes with a `AnimatedSwitcher` widget as well.